# How does Nuget package restore automatically and my program stops running on emulator

Tags: plugins, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

Hi I am developing xamarin.forms app and my program was built successfully and I was able to see output in emulator but suddenly this warning is displayed and my app is not seen in the emulator and the app is not opening

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning NU1701 Package 'Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker 1.2.1' was restored using 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework 
'.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with 
 your project.
```

I installed the .net frameworks and i tried to change it it was not possible I built the app with target framework v4.6.1 but still the same warning is displayed on the screen ,I also reinstalled vs but still no change can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see this link on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Difficult to assist you when we have so little to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still struggling to see where exactly your issue is but here is what I would recommend. Start over. Not the easiest answer but hear me out.

Create a new Xamarin project. Build with no code. Working? Take another step (add the NuGet packages you are using). Build again. As long as you are still building, continue to take small steps until you reach the point that you are at. If you ever make a change and the build fails, reverse your small change and try again. If it works, you now can see where the primary issue is and fix it.

It looked like you were also wondering how nuget restores packages. This is performed by Visual Studio anytime a missing package is detected (there is a VS setting for allowing this restore).

Comment: Hi I deleted the existing project and I created a new project and copied my entire code again but still no use and the app is not showing up in the emulator to open I built a new app with no code and tried to run it it says deployment error do you want to continue ? and the warning is displaying again and i tried changing target framework but I am not able to find .net framework version v4.6.1 i installed them again but i can see only untill v2.0 please help me what can i do?

Comment: If a brand new project cannot build and run, you have got some environment issues. These are far more difficult to diagnose. When you create a new project, what framework are you targeting (visible in the top center of the new project window)?